# Snakemake: how maintain a snakelike instance value across multiple instances of the same invocation

Tags: variables, workflow, instance, snakemake

I want to save some information within the python code that is part of my snake file, and have this information available to the python code in every instance that snakemake creates when it is running the workflow.  But a separate run of the workflow should have its own separate instance of information.

For example, say I were to create a UUID in my python code, and then later use it in the python code.  But I want the UUID to be the same one in all running instances of the workflow.  Instead, a new UUID gets created each time an instance is started.

If I start snakemake twice at the same time, I would want each of the two runs to create their own UUID, but within each run, all instances created by the run would use the same UUID.  How to do this?  Is there an identifier somewhere in the snakemake object that remains the same within one run across all instances, but changes from run to run?

Here's an example that fails with a 'No rule to produce' error:

```
import uuid
ID = str(uuid.uuid4())
print("ID:", ID)

rule all:
    output: ID
    run: print("Hello world")
```

If instead of 'run' it uses 'shell', it works fine, so I assume that Snakemake is rerunning the snakefile code when it executes the "run" portion of the rule.  How could this be modified to work, to retain the first UUID value instead of generating a second one?  Also, why isn't the ID specified for output in the rule captured when the rule is first processed, without requiring a second invocation of the python code?  Since it works with 'shell', the second invocation is not needed specifically for processing the "output" statement.

Comment: Would it work to have a `set_uuid` rule that generates this uuid and writes it in its output, and have all other rules have `rules.set_uid.output` in their input? I guess the problem would be the name of this file.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a method that seems to work: use the process group ID:

```
ID = str(os.getpgrp())
```

Multiple instances of the same pipeline have the same group ID.  However, I'm not sure if this remains true on a cluster, probably not.  In my case that didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, when you use a run block, Snakemake will invoke itself to execute that job, meaning that it also reparses the Snakefile, generating a new UUID. The same will happen on the cluster. There are good technical reasons for doing it like this (performance, the Python GIL, restrictions with pickling, simplicity and robustness of the implementation).

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but it might help to look at this: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-want-to-pass-variables-between-rules-is-that-possible

Comment: Thanks Johannes, but I have seen that section, and I don't think it answers the problem.  How would one make a persistent dictionary that had a DIFFERENT such dictionary for each instance of a snake file that is run, but that rein vocations WITHIN an instance use the SAME dictionary?  I just can't find any way to connect my running python code to a specific run of the pipeline file.